# Finding the best value for 'x' in a function: 'uniroot()' or 'optimize()'?

Tags: r, function, optimization, solver

I was wondering how best I can solve for `x` in my below function?

Can I use `uniroot()` or `optimize()`?

**Here is what I have tried (with no success):**

```
f <- function(x){ 
.8 - pt(qt(.05, df = x, lower = F)/sqrt(x + 1), df = x, ncp = .1*sqrt(x + 1), lower = F)
}

curve(f, 0, 30)

uniroot(f, c(0, 30))[[1]]

# Error in uniroot(f, c(0, 30)) : f.lower = f(lower) is NA
  In addition: Warning message:
  In qt(0.05, df = x, lower = F) : NaNs produced
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(0) in general, `uniroot()` is the correct tool for finding roots; as I've said in a previous answer, converting a root-finding problem to a minimization problem makes it more fragile.

(1) `f(0)` is `NaN`, which is causing your proximal error.

(2) `uniroot(f,c(1e-8,30))` gives

> f() values at end points not of opposite sign

So the solution you're looking for doesn't exist in the range in which you're looking for it; this is also clear from the results of the `curve()`.

(3) `uniroot(f,c(1e-8,30),extendInt="downX")` ("downX" means that uniroot is looking for a downward-crossing root) works, giving the value at 100.2549.  If you need the result to be in (0,30], you're out of luck.